# How to write a treesitter query that matches only if import is present

Tags: elixir, neovim, treesitter

I use nvim and `nvim-treesitter`, and I want to apply syntax highlighting to SQL strings in elixir files. But only when the corresponding SQL function is imported, since I don't want to match any 'ol function that is named `execute`. E.g.

```
defmodule Hello do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    print "hello"
    execute """
      alter table foo
        add constraint foo_pos check (foo > 0),
        add constraint bar_neg check (bar < 0)
      """
  end
end
```

Here, the query:

```scm
(call 
  target: (identifier) @fn-name (#eq? @fn-name "execute")
  (arguments
    (string
      (quoted_content) @str)))
```

matches the correct portion of the string, and does not trigger `print` for e.g

But this also matches:

```
defmodule Bar do
  def execute(str) do
    # This is my own function named execute
  end

  def do_bar do
    execute "not a SQL string"
  end
end
```

I wanted to write something like that:

```scm
(call
  target: (identifier) @defmodule-fn (#eq? @defmodule-fn "defmodule")
  (do_block
    (call
      target: (identifier) @use-fn (#eq? @use-fn "use")
      (arguments
        (alias) @alias (#eq? @alias "Ecto.Migration"))) 
    (call 
      target: (identifier) @fn-name (#eq? @fn-name "execute")
      (arguments
        (string
          (quoted_content) @str)))))
```

So it would only start matching `execute` functions, only if `use Ecto.Migration` was present in the module.

That code matches both, `use Ecto.Migration` as `@use-fn` and `execute` arguments as `@str`. Not what I wanted.

I expect some kind of "and" logical operator for this pattern matching problem

*P.S. Also, if there a way of adding injections only when I start up nvim in the corresponding project directory, knowing that would be amazing. I can use local `.nvimrc.lua` files to run code on project startup*